# Storing authentication key for azure cloud

Tags: python, azure

I have written a server in python that recieves an authentication key from a client that can be used to access the azure cloud blob storage. I'm having difficulties finding an optimal way of storing this key.

The key will last for quite some time so i'm considering just leaving it in the source code and compiling the program. But then the client can't ever change the key and the key would have to be changed from the source code and the program would have to be recompiled.

So i'm wondering is there any better way of storing an authentication key locally on the machine?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not enough reputation to comment...

I don't understand your problem enough, and I'm assuming you're using Azure App Services to host it.

You should at the very least be using the App Service Configuration section to inject environment variables. Alternatively you can create a KeyVault resource and use Managed Identity to grant your App Service access to KeyVault, then retrieve the secret from KeyVault within your app.